# Keep Hero widget on top of PageView pages in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to have a Hero widget displayed on top of pages in a PageView, so that when I scroll through the pages, the Hero doesn't move at all.

This is the builder for my pages:

```
Widget _buildPage({color: Color, icon: Icon, text: String}) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
      color: color,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Icon(icon)
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Text(text),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Hero(
              tag: 'examplehero',
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(...),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text(...),
                  ),
                ...
```

This is my PageView:

```
return PageView(
      children: [
        _buildPage(...),
        _buildPage(...),
        _buildPage(...),
        _buildPage(...),
      ],
    );
```

Currently, when I scroll through the pages, the hero widget acts like a regular widget, and is scrolled away with the page. How can I keep it always displayed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can extract your hero from your pageview and display your hero at the top and your page views below

Comment: @diegoveloper for some reason I didn't consider using a Stack. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122606/flutter-hero-like-transition-in-pageview) post on SO.

> This packages does what you want https://pub.dev/packages/coast
>
> It is essentially taking the same approach as Flutter’s Hero and
> HeroController: Detect when a transition is started, search through
> the element trees of the source and target pages for the widgets
> marked for animation (heroes, crabs), pair them up based on their
> tags, and finally create an entry in an Overlay whose position and
> size is the interpolation between those on the source and target
> pages.